# PL/SQL Triggers -firing question3

Tags: plsql

i try to answer this question:

> Create a trigger that displays "insert book" after each insert.

i try :

```
create trigger insert_book after insert on Books
for each rows
begin 
insert into books (id_book,title) values(12,'book12');
end;
```

Comment: Won't that insert an infinite number of books?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.... for trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_book ON [dbo].[Books] 
FOR INSERT
AS
    insert into books (id_book,title) values(12,'book12');
    PRINT 'Insert Book'
GO
```

Comment: i don't know if my answer is correct 
i just try to complete my exam 
can you help me

Comment: which server are u using ?

Comment: ok i will give you the question 
Create a trigger that displays "insert book" after each insert.

Comment: oracle,just i try to answer in my paper :p ,

Comment: check this site .... 
 https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_insert.php

Comment: It makes no sense to insert a row into  `BOOKS` as part of an `after insert` trigger on `BOOKS`. @MaestroReDa's requirement, apart from passing an exam without taking the course or reading the manual, is to display "insert book" after each insert. And he said PL/SQL.